# powershell time loop issue

Tags: powershell, time

Please I need help i have a script which checks folders on servers, if the folders get above a certain number of files, I run a function to send an email to notify us of the issue. Since the script is running permanently, I tried to set a check in the notification function that sends the emails to check when the last email was sent, if it is less than 15 minutes it just exits the if statement, if the time is after 15 minutes it must send another notification, update the last sent time and the process continues. The issue is the last update time the function is seeing is not seeing the updated variable. I have tried setting the $timesent = Get-Date variable initially outside of the function and internally but still the same issue. its almost like its seeing a different variable.

```
function sendnotification {
       $currenttime = Get-Date 
       $diff = New-Timespan -Start $timesent  -End $currenttime
       if( $diff.Minutes -ge 15 ) {
            send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtp -To $to -From $from -Subject $subject -Body $body -BodyAsHtml -Priority high -Credential $cred
            $timesent = Get-Date
       }
}
```

Comment: How do you run the script? Please provide all information necessary to reproduce the problem from scratch. We have no access to your PC!

Comment: As an aside: you want `$diff.TotalMinutes`, not `$diff.Minutes` - the latter reports only the minute _part_ of the overall time span; try `[timespan] '01:02' | select minutes, totalminutes`

Comment: powershell is ... poor ... at running for long run-times. [*sigh ...*] since you only send emails out at 15 minute intervals, could you simply run a scheduled task every 15 minutes? if not that, then perhaps every 5 minutes with a text file that has the "last email send time" in it?